# MYSQL Select max value in multi column in a date

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have table called "bowlmark" and the summary of table as below link:
(this table is recording the bowling marks for each bowler)

[image]

Here is the sample table summary:

```
bowler_id---record_date---round1mark---round2mark
101---2018-06-02---100---164
102---2018-06-02---102---120
101---2018-06-03---150---124
103---2018-06-03---200---122
```

I want to output the highest marks in each record day and show the bowler id

For the above example, I want the output to be:

```
date:2018-06-02, bowler_id:101, highestmark: 164 
date:2018-06-03, bowler_id:103, highestmark: 200 .
```

How to write this SQL query? Thanks.

Comment: This would have been easier if you had normalized your database. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization Don't get put off by the format introduction you often see, it just means that you shouldn't have 6 columns with the same type of data in it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware    what do you mean by    6 columns with the same type of data in it.??

Comment: In the top image you can see the columns: round1, round2, round3, round4, round5, round6 which all contain a mark. There should be a seperate table with all the marks in one column, and the number of the round in another column.

Comment: Please edit your question so that the sample data and expected output actually match.

Comment: Normalising your data is so much better a strategy, I wouldn't even consider the answers below

Answer (score 1):

It's a little ugly, but I was able to do it this way:

```
SELECT b.bowler_id, a.* FROM (
  SELECT record_date, MAX(GREATEST(round1mark, round2mark)) AS greatest
  FROM bowlers
  GROUP BY record_date
) a
INNER JOIN bowlers b ON
    a.record_date = b.record_date AND
    a.greatest = GREATEST(b.round1mark, b.round2mark)
```

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3718ec/17

Comment: @TobyIp You can mark the answer as accepted, by hitting the green checkmark to the left of the post.

Comment: @FrankerZ I'll give you an upvote because Tobylp clearly has done a hit a run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use greatest  and an inner join on the subquery for max  round mark

```
  select   m.bowler_id, m.record_date
     , greatest(round, round2, round3, round4, round5, round6) highest_mark
  from bowlmark m 
  inner join (
    select record_date 
      , max(greatest(round, round2, round3, round4, round5, round6)) as max_round
    from bowlmark
    group by record_date 
  ) t on t.record_date = m.record_date 
        and greatest(round, round2, round3, round4, round5, round6) = t.max_round
```

*anyway   a proper datababase normalization could help you to avoid this kind of problems*

Comment: There is an ambiguous column `record_date`.